# How can i run two different instances of my chat app built on expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing a chat app using expo. I want to test the app using two different users. How can i do that in expo ?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely run multiple clients at the same time with expo.

If you are using physical devices, you just need to scan the QR code on both devices. If you are using a simulator and a physical device, just launch the simulator, press "c" to display the QR code and scan it on your device.